# Scrape dynamic rendering data with click button

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I have a lot of different scrapers, but all of them are working with server rendering pages or parse responses from API endpoints.

But now I have two very specific web sites to scrape:

**First.**

Single page, we should click on seach button to get first 10 items. To get next 10 items - click button "Next". After 2-3 sec data in search section is rerendered. On click "Next" I get dummy unparsed data  from `vaadin` service. So data can be parsed only from rendered HTML page.

**Second.**

Same single page with same principles ( click search button to get init data, click Next button to load new data). But additionally I need click on every items to get all data to scrape ( I scrape some data from rendered search result + from modal window after click on each search result item)

Question - is it possible to scrape such websites with scrapy and splash? I know about selenium, but it's quite heavy and slow, I need other solution. Never worked with splash, but if I am not mistaken it's possisble to imitate click via lua script..

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest avoiding Splash and instead [reproducing the underlying requests](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html#reproducing-requests).

The main issue I see here with going the Splash route is that, if there is no URL that you can use to access a page other than the first page from a web browser, and since Splash does not support (AFAIK) resuming a previous rendering, you would need Splash to have each request to Splash run a Lua script that clicks Next, waits and repeats for N pages.

If reproducing the requests is out of the picture for some reason, using an interactive headless browser (Selenium, Puppeteer) instead of a rendering service (Splash) may be better.

Comment: I also suggest Puppeteer for this website even it has not best performance.